# Retrieve a .csv download hidden behind a hyperlink using Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to use Rvest to download a .csv hidden behind the "download the complete db" link from the website: http://friedmanlab.weizmann.ac.il/McPAS-TCR/

However, when using inspect element in chrome, the href link takes a second to appear when loading the url and therefore when fetching that data, the href is not taken into the output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("http://friedmanlab.weizmann.ac.il/McPAS-TCR/")

page %>% html_nodes("a")
```

**output**:

```
 [1] <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">\n          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigat ...
 [2] <a href="#tab-5712-1" data-toggle="tab" data-value="1">Home</a>
 [3] <a href="#tab-5712-2" data-toggle="tab" data-value="2">Search Database</a>
 [4] <a href="#tab-5712-3" data-toggle="tab" data-value="3">Help</a>
 [5] <a href="#tab-5712-4" data-toggle="tab" data-value="About">About</a>
 [6] <a id="downloadDB" class="btn btn-default shiny-download-link " href="" target="_blank">\n                            <i  ...
 [7] <a href="#tab-7476-1" data-toggle="tab" data-value="FreeText">Enter Query</a>
 [8] <a href="#tab-7476-2" data-toggle="tab" data-value="file_upload">Or: upload file</a>
 [9] <a id="saveCSV" class="btn btn-default shiny-download-link " href="" target="_blank">\n                          <i class ...
[10] <a href="#dbglossary">Database Glossary</a>
[11] <a href="#analysis_examples">Usage examples</a>
[12] <a href="#dbsearch">How to search the database</a>
[13] <a href="#additionalResources">Additional resources</a>
[14] <a name="dbglossary">Database Glossary</a>
[15] <a href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/">http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/</a>
[16] <a href="http://www.iedb.org/">www.iedb.org</a>
[17] <a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed" target="_blank">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed</a>
[18] <a name="analysis_examples">Usage examples</a>
[19] <a id="dbsearch">How to search the database</a>
[20] <a name="additionalResources">Additional Resources</a>
```

[6] would be the index i'd like to select for and then grab the href.

Is it possible to establish a connection with this website, wait for the href attribute to appear and then scrape and retrieve the download link? I've read about Sys.sleep(), so maybe if I could load the website, then wait, then get the href that would work.

Thank you, this is my first post so I apologize for any mistakes! I appreciate any help.

Comment: The irony ... a shiny-served document defeating `rvest` scraping ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. A combination of rselenium and rvest and waiting for at least 15 seconds for the R shiny server to give up the link

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://friedmanlab.weizmann.ac.il/McPAS-TCR/"

#connect to server
rd <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "firefox")

#set client
remDr <- rd$client

#navigate to url
remDr$navigate(url)

#need to wait 15s at least for the href to appear
Sys.sleep(15)

#reading the html page
ext <- xml2::read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% 
  #selecting for links
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  #getting those of attr href
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  #the link allways includes the word session
  stringr::str_subset("session")

#read in the csv
mc_db <- read.csv(paste0(url, ext), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```